# Keep linebreaks when getting text from <textarea>

Tags: html, textarea, visual-web-developer

I'm building a site with Visual Web Developer with C# and HTML.

I have a page where users can write feedback about my site in a textarea tag and then submit (in the textarea they can do a line-break everywhere).

The problem is that when I get back the text they wrote it appears without the linebreaks, for example:

if the user wrote:

```
"Hello, my name is
Omer N."
```

When I get it back it will look like this: "Hello, my name is Omer N.".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the line break is gone when you get it from the browser, or is it perhaps when you later show the text in the browser that the line break doesn't show up?

Comment: I enter the text to a String and then present it in a <p> by using <%=theString %> inside <p>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you are storing the values.  Remember that HTML and general input from fields following the whitespace rule, it will truncate/condense white space into a single entity.

```
So "Wide      String" = "Wide String" and:

"Multi-line
string
here" will be truncated to "Multi-line string here" as you have experienced.
```

This is the default behavior.

So to keep your line breaks, spacing, etc.. you need to [escape it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) or a process of [encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [decoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), before storing it.

It is explained [here:](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/20/how-to-retain-carriage-returns-or-line-breaks-in-an-asp-net-web-page)

> Many newcomers to web development cannot get their head around why the 
>   carriage returns they made in their data on input from a textarea, or from a 
>   text file, Excel spreadsheet etc. do not appear when the web page renders.
>
> The solution is fairly obvious once the newcomer realizes that a web 
>   page is only the browser's interpretation of html markup, and that a
>   new line in html is represented by the 
>  tag. So what is needed
>   is a way to swap carriage returns or line feeds with the 
>  tag.
>   Well, a way to Replace() them, actually.

```
<%# Eval("MyMultiLineValue").ToString().Replace(<linebreak>,"<br />") %>
```

> The string.Replace() method allows this, but we also need to identify 
>   what we want to replace with the html tag. How is a new line 
>    represented in C# or VB.Net?
>
> In C#, it's "\r\n", while in VB.Net, it's vbcrlf. However, there is
>   also a language independent option that does just the same thing:
>   Environment.NewLine.

```
<%# Eval("MyMultiLineValue").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br />") %>
```

Hope this helps! :)